# How to calculate First Day Of Year from the user input?

Tags: asp.net

Here is my problem.

If user input the date=31/12/2012, I need to Calculate First Day Of Year from the user input(01/01/2012) in asp.

Can you explain any one or any sample code related this.

Your help would be very appreciated.
 thanks for your time and hints.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first day and the last day of the current year in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181113/how-to-get-the-first-day-and-the-last-day-of-the-current-year-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

1) Find year from input date

```
int year = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2013", new CultureInfo("en-US")).Year;
```

2) Now find Day of 1/1/year

```
String strday = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
```